# Data Validation in Pentaho using regular expression

Tags: regex, pentaho, kettle

I have these sample data. (**Current Balance** is numeric field and has some bad records which need to be replaced)

```
Accno,Cust_id,gender,DOB,Current_balance
0008647447654709299,87128110,M,29/02/1960,184126.23
0008650447626799299,143500723,F,4/18/1967,165198.85
0008651447674209299,479941323,M,5/5/1979,NULL
0008653447693589299,687746622,M,18-08-1981,#20
0008654447606469299,890134223,M,18-08-1983,0
0008655447659179299,684451923,F,10/9/1982,142.25
0008658447686789299,57470921,F,25-02-1978,458518.25
0008669447629759299,57470925,M,23-01-1981,xx
```

I need to validate data in Pentaho and want the output like below :

```
Accno,Cust_id,gender,DOB,Current_balance
0008647447654709299,87128110,M,29/02/1960,184126.23
0008650447626799299,143500723,F,4/18/1967,165198.85
0008651447674209299,479941323,M,5/5/1979,
0008653447693589299,687746622,M,18-08-1981,
0008654447606469299,890134223,M,18-08-1983,0
0008655447659179299,684451923,F,10/9/1982,142.25
0008658447686789299,57470921,F,25-02-1978,458518.25
0008669447629759299,57470925,M,23-01-1981,
```

**That means the validator pass the good row(s) and replace those bad data into null value.**
Can anyone suggest how can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Pentaho, but to point you in the right direction, you can use the following regex:

```
,(?=[^,]+$)(?!\d+(\.\d{2})).*$
```

In **Multi-line mode**

If you replace all matches with `','` you should have the desired output.

[Working on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%2C%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%2C%5D%2B%24%29%28%3F!%5Cd%2B%28%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29.%2a%24&input=0008647447654709299%2C87128110%2CM%2C29%2F02%2F1960%2C184126.23%0A0008650447626799299%2C143500723%2CF%2C4%2F18%2F1967%2C165198.85%0A0008651447674209299%2C479941323%2CM%2C5%2F5%2F1979%2CNULL%0A0008653447693589299%2C687746622%2CM%2C18-08-1981%2C%2320%0A0008654447606469299%2C890134223%2CM%2C18-08-1983%2C0%0A0008655447659179299%2C684451923%2CF%2C10%2F9%2F1982%2C142.25%0A0008658447686789299%2C57470921%2CF%2C25-02-1978%2C458518.25%0A0008669447629759299%2C57470925%2CM%2C23-01-1981%2Cxx)

---

RegexPlanet translates this into the following Java regex (looks like you just need to escape the backslashes):

```
,(?=[^,]+$)(?!\\d+(\\.\\d{2})).*$
```

So in Java I guess you'd use something like:

```
str.replaceAll("(?m),(?=[^,]+$)(?!\\d+(\\.\\d{2})).*$", ",");
```

The `(?m)` at the start is the multi-line flag mentioned above.

Comment: In Pentaho all your Regexes are Java, so you just have to translate the above to Java format in your `Replace in string` step.

Comment: how can i translate this in JAVA format in Pentaho?? actually i'm new in Pentaho...

Comment: Just updated the question with what I think is the correct Java usage.